# From where will Santa deliver after North Pole melts?

Tags: alternate-worlds, mythical-creatures, santa-claus, climate-change

I know that Global Warming is controversial topic, so for scope of this question please accept below statements as facts. (And if you have hard time accepting them, just assume alternate Earth):

By year 2030, the North Atlantic ocean will melt completely, leaving no ice behind. Santa Claus is aware of that and tries to find better place from where he should deliver the Christmas presents.

**Where should Santa Claus realocate his hideout after North Pole melts completely?**

For sure it needs to be somewhere where you meet no people and it should be snowy. But where on Earth should Santa go?

Comment: Why would Santa keep delivering if we have been naughty enough to destroy his home?

Comment: Why would Santa consider a child born in 2025 as "naughty" because their parents caused global warming?

Comment: Anyone for "original sin"? He's a Saint, so strong catholic influences, it would be reasonable for him to blame descendants in perpetuity.

Comment: Santa is not actually at the North Pole: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/how-do-santa-and-the-reindeer-survive-delivery-night

Comment: given all he's done could we not all pitch in for a refurbished aircraft carrier ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Mt Gunnbjörn

[Mt. Gunnbjörn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnbj%C3%B8rn_Fjeld) is the highest mountain inside the Arctic circle.  It is located inside glacial ice and will remain cold long after sea level locations remain above freezing year round.  If Santa locates in the Northern shade, the ice is likely to remain well past the time when it has melted lower.  There are several other mountains of similar, if lower, height that might suffice if you prefer the anonymity of second.  Of course, most people won't climb up the cold side anyway.

Another possibility is Mt. Everest.  Gunnbjörn is considerably lower than Everest.  Everest's very height means that it is below freezing year round at the summit, even though it is almost within the tropics.  While Everest has a certain number of climbers, they tend to follow a few paths.  Santa could simply locate somewhere that is not climbable.  After all, he has a flying sleigh.  And of course, he's only moving in and out around Christmas.  Climbers come through around May when the winds are lower.  Santa could bury the entrance then.

Once global warming overcomes these places, there's always off-world.  If you are not insistent on water-based snow, Pluto remains quite cold year round and will be unaffected by global warming due to atmospheric changes on Earth.  Mars is a bit closer and may have water-based ice as well.  Not sure about snow, I don't know that it has enough atmosphere for precipitation.

Santa also may want to consider a climate-controlled space habitat located in orbit around the Earth.  Painted black with one-way glass (light can come in but not go out), his habitat can evade most notice.  A little practical application of stealth technology should give it a similar radar footprint to a communications satellite or a piece of debris.  By that time, there should be enough junk in orbit that Santa's workshop won't seem out of place.

Comment: Several hundred people attempt to climb Mt. Everest each year. I wouldn't really call that a place where people won't be met. And anyone looking up at night would be able to find Santa if he relocated to an orbiting space station.

Answer (score 8):

**Antarctica**. Judging by the evidence that has been shipped by mistake ( Xmas cards featuring reindeer *and* penguins ) the Claus corporation relocation has already started.

Answer (score 0):

Santa stays on the northpool. Once global warming take its corse the north pool turn from a ice land to a paradise. And Santa likes the heat.

Answer (score 0):

The same magical shield that Santa currently uses to conceal his community of sweatshops for the height-challenged also filters out enough UV to easily maintain his desired climate. If required, significant HVAC capabilities can be added to that end. After all, if they can cool an [indoor ski hill in the Dubai desert](http://www.skidubai.com/ski-dubai/resort/), cooling a small northern town will be a snap.

As such, reloaction is not required, and his address will remain in Canada, [specifically at](https://www.canadapost.ca/web/en/blogs/announcements/details.page?article=2015/11/19/time_to_write_to_san&cattype=announcements&cat=newsreleases):

```
Santa Claus
North Pole
Canada
H0H 0H0
```