# Is Santa taking off risk creating a black hole, and will the good kids receive presents survive it?

Tags: science-based, physics, energy, relativity, santa-claus

Santa has to visit roughly [822 houses a second](http://www.daclarke.org/Humour/santa.html) on Christmas day.  At each house he has to stop, go down the chimney to deliver toys, then take off for the next home in a millisecond's time.

As the brilliant people on Stack Exchange already knows Santa's sleigh, weighed down by toys, weighs [more then an aircraft carrier](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31460/how-much-does-santas-sleigh-weigh), and would surely crush any house it landed on if not for it's ability to fly!  When Santa takes off he has to accelerate from a dead stop to sufficiently high speeds to make it to the next house over in a fraction of a second, and decelerate back to a stop at the next house.  This has to require an astronomical amount of energy to pull off!

What would Santa's take off do to the local vicinity when he travels between homes?  Is there any way to survive Santa's take-off?  What is the risk of the kind of energy required to accelerate an aircraft carrier's worth of toys that fast creating a black hole?

For bonus points how many cookies does Santa have to feed his reindeer for them to have the energy to pull his sleigh all night?

Comment: Ask one question not four, please.

Comment: Clearly as none of these issues have come to pass, santa uses a reactionless drive system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many Santas are required?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/134484/how-many-santas-are-required)

Comment: Santa does not have nearly enough mass/density for a black hole to be a problem.  I'd refocus your question to either, "What would Santa's take off do to the local vicinity when he travels between homes?" or "Is there any way to survive Santa's take-off?"